# How to modify request headers in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

**I have a need to add a header to each request to the server.**

I do it this using [_midleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware) like this:

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest): Promise<NextResponse> {
    req.headers.append('x-custom-header', '1337');
    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

If I do `console.log(req.headers)` I see that the request header has been added:

```
BaseHeaders [Headers] {
    [Symbol(map)]: {
      accept: [ '*/*' ],
      'accept-encoding': [ 'gzip, deflate, br' ],
      'accept-language': [ 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' ],
      'cache-control': [ 'no-cache' ],
      connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
      cookie: ...,
      host: ...,
      pragma: [ 'no-cache' ],
      referer: ...,
      ...,
      'x-custom-header': [ '1337' ]
    }
  }
```

However, this does not modify the request: there is no request header in the browser.

**Why is the request not modified? Are there alternative ways to modify request headers in Next.js?**

Comment: Request is already sent right. They are modified before reaching your API code. Chrome will not know of it

Comment: Please provide a MRE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I found some discussions on this topic, maybe it will be useful:


[Modify request objects within middleware function](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/31188)  
 
and

[Add support for middleware rewrite proxy headers](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/31188)

Comment: @aiw thanks, I've tried some of the things suggested here and they're either for the response (not the request) or they get added to `req.headers` within the middleware but don't get passed on externally with the rewrite I'm trying to do (the "hacky workaround" of adding + stripping them doesn't work because they don't even make it that far)

Comment: @PaulS. Same thing. I assume you want to send tokens for api requests. I solved a similar problem a little dirty, but simple by putting data in a cookie, which automatically goes into the headers of outgoing requests. Perhaps this compromise will suit you as well. Otherwise, I couldn't think of anything other than interceptors for fetch queries or fetcher function wrapper which will add the necessary headings to each query.

Comment: So you want to change the headers of the incoming request before it hits the destination endpoint in your server, is that it?

Comment: I want to change the request headers before it is sent to api endpoint, so that the backend understands that it is being addressed by someone who have needed access rights.

Comment: Then it sounds like you want to add it to the request that the browser sends, which means middleware is not right for you since it only allows you to add an extra processing step when the request hits the backend. You want to add an extra header when calling the backend. However, this sounds like a security risk since you then have to expose the material allowing access rights to the browser. Are users authenticated in your app and is the content of this extra header individual per user or one for all? Is it like an api key? Normally you would just use sessions stored in cookies for this.

Comment: If you reveal more about the use-case, I think you might get some help. Middleware is not the way forward since they only return the response, e.g. no changes to the request will propagate.

Comment: @fast-reflexes, You're right, I didn't consider that middleware is triggered after the request has been sent by the browser. The problem is that the backend also does not receive modified requests. I don't mind if the outgoing request is intercepted by Next.js server and modified before sent to api, it seems to me that it fits well with the _middleware concept. However, it doesn't work now.

Comment: @fast-reflexes, if I understand the nuances correctly, I would like to see the following.

browser request -> next.js web server -> backend server.

Where the next.js web server stage modifies all outgoing browser requests.
That is, in my case it should be adds the necessary headers

Comment: @aiw the NextJS web server IS the same as the backend... Are you trying to forward a request to another web server? NextJS is NOT a browser-only framework, it is a backend as well and the middleware you're using is ONLY executed in the backend. This is in contrast with for example create-react-app which ONLY lives in the browser and is NOT a backend as well.

Comment: @fast-reflexes, I understand. Yes, i trying to forward a request to another web server.

Comment: @aiw Ok so you will send a request from the browser to your own backend, connect to YOUR api and then make a request to ANOTHER web server. Do you want to REDIRECT client to that web server or do you want to make a request ON BEHALF of the client and then return the response from the other server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242113/discussion-between-aiw-and-fast-reflexes).

Answer (score 12):

Looks like starting from Next.js v13.0.0 it is now possible to modify request headers: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#setting-headers

Here's a code snippet from the documentation:

```js
// middleware.ts

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // Clone the request headers and set a new header `x-hello-from-middleware1`
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
  requestHeaders.set('x-hello-from-middleware1', 'hello')

  // You can also set request headers in NextResponse.rewrite
  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      // New request headers
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  })

  // Set a new response header `x-hello-from-middleware2`
  response.headers.set('x-hello-from-middleware2', 'hello')
  return response
}
```

Comment: this wont work for cache headers

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me. The header is changed in middleware and reflected in getServerSideProps.

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) : Promise<NextResponse> {
    const response = NextResponse.next()
    response.headers.append("key", "value")
    return response
}


//inside page
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(store => async (context) => {
    //the headers are changed here
    console.log(context.res.getHeaders())
    return {
      props: {}
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That is altering the response headers, not the request headers.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question actually, since although I've done a lot of work on SPA architectures I hadn't looked into nextjs and its SSR behavior.

**CUSTOM HEADERS AND CROSS SITE REQUEST FORGERY**

A good angle for solving your problem is to think about other common use cases for custom headers and look for a nextjs solution. A security related one is to send a [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-of-custom-request-headers) custom request header, eg `example-csrf`, in data changing API requests.

When I searched for nextjs ways to do that I found this [next-csrf library](https://github.com/j0lv3r4/next-csrf) and I suspect it will enable you to solve your problem. From what I can see, it works like this, though I think you'll understand the nextjs specifics better than me:

- The [middleware class](https://github.com/j0lv3r4/next-csrf/blob/main/src/middleware/csrf.ts) runs on the website when a
  request is first received, and creates the request header value
- The value is then provided to React components, which will run in the browser:

```
import { getCsrfToken } from '../lib/csrf';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} csrfToken={getCsrfToken()} />
}
```

- Also I think the React views you write can then send that value from the browser if required:

```js
const response = await fetch('/api/protected', {
    'headers': {
        'XSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken,
    }
});
```

There are some issues / feedback posted on the CSRF GitHub repo also - reading some of those may help you with your own solution.

**ARCHITECTURE THOUGHTS**

It is interesting looking at this, since I know nextjs is highly respected and enables better SEO etc. It also reminds me of older website technologies where developers often struggled, due to having to switch between client side and server side code. Being in control of data requests is an important technical foundation.

Out of interest, at Curity we have some code resources focused on SPA security, CDN deployment and developer experience, in case any of this is ever useful, for future reference. We do not use SSR currently, but we may want to say more about SSR use cases in future:

- [Sending CSRF headers](https://github.com/curityio/spa-using-token-handler/blob/main/spa/src/api/apiClient.ts#L58)
- [Token handler pattern code example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-spa-example/)

Comment: Hey, from the perspective of the client's browser this is all done on the same request to the same domain, ie. `browser -> next -> api (as a rewrite proxy) -> next -> browser`. In the meantime I'm using a server-side `fetch` to get the data and then forwarding that response back manually, but all it really needs to work the "built-in way" is an extra header :/

Comment: @PaulS. I don't quite understand how the server side fetch helped you automatically  add the necessary header? What do you do with requests with dynamic params (for e.g, submit fetch for form with input or selects) that cannot be done on the server? What did you mean about "forwarding that response back manually"?

Comment: Apologies for the previous incorrect answer, and I'm interested in how this turns out. I've posted an updated answer based on a common use case for custom headers. I hope this helps, since if your can work out how to send a CSRF request header you will then be able to solve your own custom header problem.

Comment: @aiw as we have access to a request object we can build a new request in the middleware, copying in form data/etc as required, perform a `fetch` with the new request object wait for it and then send the response back to `res`, a bit like you might do in `express` - this basically loses any benefits of using nextjs over express for the particular route though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom headers in a similar way you would by [adding security headers](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/security-headers), by using `headers` in your `next.config.js`:

```
// next.config.js

// You can choose which headers to add to the list
// after learning more below.
const securityHeaders = []

module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // Apply these headers to all routes in your application.
        source: '/:path*',
        headers: securityHeaders,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: This method works for the response headers, but I need to change the request headers.