# Nextjs 13: Modified Cookie request header in nextjs middleware (v13.1.0) does not reflect in request.cookies field in getServerSideProps

Tags: cookies, next.js, http-headers, middleware

I'd like to add some cookie (values) to the request in my nextjs middleware routine, in such a way that they show up in the `request.cookies` field in my `getServerSideProps` routine (which gets called after the middleware runs).

I already found out that, starting from nextjs v13.1.0, I can manipulate request headers in my middleware using the following `RequestHeaders` mechanism (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74512684/1426222) and this indeed seems to work (before v13.1.0 request headers apparently were immutable)...

So If I add this in my middleware:

```
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
  requestHeaders.set('Cookie', requestHeaders.get('Cookie') + ';test-cookie=test-value');

  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  })
  return response;
```

And I log `request.headers['cookie']` in the `getServerSideProps`, it shows that the new cookie was indeed added to the header.

So far, so good. However, `request.cookies` does not reflect the newly added cookie...

Is there some way to let nextjs re-evaluate the `request.cookies` fields based on the modified request cookie header in my middleware  or is this just not possible?